# Django queryset - differing results for query and query.count()

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a django model with three fields and I'm trying to find the duplicates. If I run:
`cls.objects.values('institution','person','title').annotate(records=Count('person')).filter(records__gt=1).count()` I get `152` as the output.

However, if I attempt to see what those records are and run the same query without the count() `cls.objects.values('institution','person','title').annotate(records=Count('person')).filter(records__gt=1)`
I get `<QuerySet []>`.

Any idea what's going on? If I add a .first() I get null, and a [0] gives me an out of range error, however the count continues to return 152. Running SQL directly on the database shows there are in fact 152 matching entries so the count is correct, but I can't seem to get the queryset (or any elements in it) to return.

Comment: Can you share the queries generated by both? It could make us understand better what is happening.
`cls.objects.values('institution','person','title').annotate(records=Count('person')).filter(records__gt=1).query.__str__()` and for the count:
`from django.db import connection` run the count query and then get it from `connection.queries`.

Comment: Sure, here's the raw one: ```{'sql': 'SELECT "companies_employee"."institution", "companies_employee"."person_id", "companies_employee"."title", COUNT("companies_employee"."person_id") AS "records" FROM "companies_employee" GROUP BY "companies_employee"."institution", "companies_employee"."person_id", "companies_employee"."title", "companies_employee"."startdate" HAVING COUNT("companies_employee"."person_id") > 1 LIMIT 21',
  'time': '11.684'}```

Comment: and here's the count: ```{'sql': 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT "companies_employee"."institution" AS Col1, "companies_employee"."person_id" AS Col2, "companies_employee"."title" AS Col3, COUNT("companies_employee"."person_id") AS "records" FROM "companies_employee" GROUP BY "companies_employee"."institution", "companies_employee"."person_id", "companies_employee"."title" HAVING COUNT("companies_employee"."person_id") > 1) subquery',
  'time': '7.193'}```

Comment: There's something injecting the `"companies_employee"."startdate"` in your GROUP BY. Maybe an overrided `Model.objects` Manager/Queryset. Could you to force Django's default manager? `cls.objects = models.Manager()` and perform the query again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The startdate injection into the GROUP BY mentioned by @JoVi in the comment turned out to be the issue here. It was being added due to it being a default sort in the django model definition. Adding an empty .order_by() to the query removed that and resulted in the query working as expected.